# Desktop shutdown needs to be triggered multiple times

Tags: shutdown

There is something in my setup, which leads to shutdown problems. Usually I have to trigger the "Shutdown" action more than once.

I don't know if it's distribution specific at all. At least it happens with xubuntu 16.04 and kubuntu 17.04 in their default desktops.

It's not always the same. Sometimes, it directly shuts down. Everything fine. But sometimes, it just closes a few windows. I have to trigger it again then. In most cases, it works after the second attempt. In rare cases it completely fails. Sometimes not even /sbin/shutdown works afterwards (very rare). Sometimes it helps to manually close some windows, although there were no problems with them, and the processes reacted instantly on that. In all error cases, the trouble begins somewhere before actually closing the desktop. I can still see the wallpaper and typically can interact with the remaining parts.

Something is obviously disturbing the shutdown procedure. I don't know if comes from a particular desktop application I typically have opened. Or from my homedir mounting via pam-mount, or some background processes.

I could not find any information about how shutdown works in technical detail in a modern Ubuntu system. Most things I found were aged or too short. Which components are involved, which logfiles are worth reading? What could be typical pitfalls leading to those issues?

Comment: Have you tried old-school and used init 0 as your shutdown command?

Comment: @SDsolar: No, I would like to stay with what the system implements. I never had great times with changes like that in the long run. What is the idea behind that change? That will lead to a rather brutal shutdown?!

Comment: The system implements run levels.  Runlevel 2  multi-user.  Runlevel 1 single.  init 6 reboot.  Init 0 shut down.  They are just hidden behind the shutdown and reboot commands.   Those are what the system implements.   You asked why it would be slow, so I asked if you had tried the REAL unix command for shutdown.   Init 0 flushes all the disk buffers and does what it takes to stop all the services cleanly, then turn off.  Now what is REALLY hard on a unix system is to suddenly lose power - that is the definition of brutal, and can be fatal - better have good backups if you start doing that.

Comment: @SDsolar: Are you sure this is actually the case? As far as I know, the init stuff is just the last part of a complete desktop stutdown, while the desktop environment typically closes the applications before in a friendly way, asking for unsaved changes, and so on. And, in modern Ubuntu, runlevels are even just wrappers around some systemd constructs?!

Comment: The shutdown command actually uses the init 0 to perform the shutdown.  The only difference is that it gives you a delay time first.  That's why you think it is not working.  And If you simply pull the power you can damage your file system.  In the old days we had to issue sync;sync;sync before init 0 to make sure it didn't damage it.  If it is in the middle of writing to a directory when you pull power you can lose that directory or the entire structure.  Then you have to restore the SD card from an .img file you have made previously with Win32DiskImager.  init 0 is your fastest safe method